# How do I import data from Manychat to Google Sheets?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing some data from Manychat API but it says 401 error (Wrong Format Token)

The link is here

```
=ImportJSONBasicAuth("https://api.manychat.com/fb/page/getCustomFields?Authorization=Bearer my_token_id", "my_username", "my_password", "/data", "noInherit, noTruncate")
```

There is a space between `Bearer` & `my_token_id` so how could I encode this to import successfully into google sheets?

Manychat give API Key like this

```
Name: Authorization
Value: Bearer my_token_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can add this function inside the Google Script Editor and check if
>   this works. I have tweaked the function a bit.

```
function ImportJSONBasicAuthForManyChat(url, tokenFromManyChat, query, parseOptions) {
  var header = {headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + tokenFromManyChat}};
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, header, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```

In the google sheet use it like this

`=ImportJSONBasicAuth("https://api.manychat.com/fb/page/getCustomFields", "TOKEN_FROM_MANY_CHAT", "/data", "noInherit, noTruncate")`

Comment: I have tried but no success...Thank you for your help!
I will try myself continuously and if you want to suggest to me then please feel free to send me a message!

Comment: Do let me know if you manage to solve this. here is my email - akolsawala2@gmail.com

Comment: Hello Ayyub, finally I have done and successfully imported my MANYCHAT custom fields into google sheets and this credit goes to you

So many times on that day you HELPED me and figured it that what causes it and I finally did it but the things is that, ican't update this file automatically by per minute like before.... but it is updating but in my view, it is not updated by f per minute like I set before...

Comment: Ayyub, I have sent you the email please check your inbox

Answer (score 0):

> You can paste [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/master/ImportJSON.gs) in the script editor section of your google
>   sheet and use this function for fetching the data

```
=ImportJSONBasicAuth("https://api.manychat.com/fb/page/getCustomFields", "username", "password", "/data", "noInherit, noTruncate")
```

Comment: Request failed for https://api.manychat.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"status":"error","message":"Wrong format token"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 220).

Comment: @Paresh did u try to execute the same API from the ManyChat Swagger? Just check if it works from there. https://support.manychat.com/support/solutions/articles/36000070776-manychat-api

Comment: I have tried and I am getting the result in manychat

{"status":"success","data":[{"id":2139832,"name":"Coupon_Code","type":"text","description":""}

Comment: but my concern is in google sheets
the value is Bearer my_token_id (I have remained the same space in manychat)

Comment: Just read a Github Document according to it, you need not to pass the token in the Url, it automatically calculates and appends the Bearer token from your user_name and password.

Comment: O I c, I will let you know if something goes well or wrong

Comment: @Paresh I have updated the code please let me know if it works for u.

Comment: No Ayyub, I have tried at so many times but result is same (Wrong Format Token)

Comment: How do you use this function `=ImportJSONBasicAuth ` is it a custom function for you? if yes, can I see it?

Comment: Ayyub, I have added 2 images...001 is getting the result but 002 is getting error...both are different but I wanted to show you the difference

Answer (score 0):

[Image 001 is getting perfect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAYUu.jpg)[Image 002 is getting error (401)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLXve.jpg)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce this specific scenario for me since I dont have account / access to get API Key for me. But if it work for you in one example then it should work for manychat also. Just want to know if you are passing the correct user name and password for this to work. OR you can maybe try making the same call from POSTMAN and see if its working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will let you know if something is done properly or not!